# Document library web-part cannot see document version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-document-library

On a Modern page using a document web-part I do not have the option to see version history.

[image: no version history]

However going to the document through the site contents page and default libraries I can see the version history option, I notice that this page stutters a little bit then more actions like version history are added the the context menu

[image: with version history option]

I cannot remember if in the past I have 
been able to see version history in the document library web part of a modern page or if it is a known limitation of the document library web-part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my analysis, this is a known limitation of document library web-part in SharePoint Online Modern experience.

I have seen the similar behavior in past. There are so many functionalities that are not supported in modern experience yet.

Version history was supported in classic SharePoint webpart pages. hope Microsoft provides this functionality in modern experience too in near future.

However you can submit a new idea on [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/). If the idea gets the required votes in time then Microsoft implements those ideas in future updates.